# Rails Ignoring Database.yml configurations and launching Webrick instead of MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new to Rails and I'm still trying to get everything set up right on Snow Leopard. I'm trying to install Ruby, Rails, RVM, phpmyadmin, and MySQL. So far I have Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.9, RVM and MySQL (5.5.14?) installed and each of them seems to be working fine on their own.

My major obstacle is that I'm trying to start-up MySQL in my test rails app and it's completely ignoring my database.yml file configurations (shown below) and is launching Webrick instead. I saved this database.yml file and did 'bundle install' and it says that everything is loaded.

database.yml contents:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/development_database
  username: root
  password: ###### [password hidden]
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: db/test_database
  username: root
  password: ###### [password hidden]
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

 production:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: db/production_database
    username: root
    password: ####### [password hidden]
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
```

FYI: I was having this issue [version of mysql2 (0.3.2) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5840742) which I was trying to troubleshoot when rails wouldn't stop loading webrick.

Any help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick clarification:

MySQL is the db and WEBrick is the web server. They can both be in use simultaneously. What leads you to think that mysql isn't running? Have you done rake db:create, have any models/migrations in place?

MySQL is actually replacing SQLite3, not WEBrick...

Comment: hmm... sorry for my ignorance and thank you. i guess that explains why i couldn't find any answers.

Comment: the reason that I thought it was mysql related is because I get this error when I navigate to phpmyadmin on my local host "Cannot load mysql extension. Please check your PHP configuration. - Documentation". I tried to change my php.ini file to connect it to mysql but that didn't seem to work, so i figured it had to do with mysql not loading or something. still trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you're using "db/development_database" as the database name. Usually if you're using mysql as your database server, you'd simply put the name of the database. I've never tried to, but I'm pretty sure, you can't use the '/'.