# Ruby read CSV file as UTF-8 and/or convert ASCII-8Bit encoding to UTF-8

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, csv, utf-8

I'm using ruby 1.9.2

I'm trying to **parse a CSV file** that contains some French words (e.g. spécifié) and place the contents in a MySQL database.

When I read the lines from the CSV file,

```
file_contents = CSV.read("csvfile.csv", col_sep: "$")
```

The elements come back as Strings that are **ASCII-8BIT** encoded (spécifié becomes sp\xE9cifi\xE9), and strings like "spécifié" are then NOT properly saved into my MySQL database.

[Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/) says that ASCII-8BIT is really "binary" data meaning that CSV has no idea how to read the appropriate encoding.

So, if I try to make CSV force the encoding like this:

`file_contents = CSV.read("csvfile.csv", col_sep: "$", encoding: "UTF-8")`

I get the following error

```
ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8:
```

If I go back to my original ASCII-8BIT encoded Strings and examine the String that my CSV read as ASCII-8BIT, it looks like this "Non sp\xE9cifi\xE9" instead of "Non spécifié".

I can't convert "Non sp\xE9cifi\xE9" to "Non spécifié" by doing this 
`"Non sp\xE9cifi\xE9".encode("UTF-8")`

because I get this error:

`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8`,

which Katz indicated would happen because ASCII-8BIT isn't really a proper String "encoding".

**Questions:**

1. **Can I get CSV to read my file in the appropriate encoding?  If so, how?**
2. **How do I convert an ASCII-8BIT string to UTF-8 for proper storage in MySQL?**

Comment: It sounds like the file might not be UTF-8 encoded; have you checked the actual encoding of the file?

Comment: Your file is not encoded in UTF-8. é in UTF-8 should be `C3 A9`, not `E9`. Looks like you're dealing with ISO-8859-1 instead.

Comment: I think I figured it out:  my_ascii_8bit_string.unpack("C*").pack("U*") seems to work.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, the file isn't UTF-8 encoded, but I wanted a way to do it via ruby

Comment: Then the correct way would be to read the CSV as ISO-8859-1 and convert the result from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 using encoding conversion functions. Unfortunately my Ruby isn't good enough to tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) is right, that is ISO8859-1 (AKA Latin-1) encoded text. Try this:

```
file_contents = CSV.read("csvfile.csv", col_sep: "$", encoding: "ISO8859-1")
```

And if that doesn't work, you can use [`Iconv`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/classes/Iconv.html) to fix up the individual strings with something like this:

```
require 'iconv'
utf8_string = Iconv.iconv('utf-8', 'iso8859-1', latin1_string).first
```

If `latin1_string` is `"Non sp\xE9cifi\xE9"`, then `utf8_string` will be `"Non spécifié"`. Also, `Iconv.iconv` can unmangle whole arrays at a time:

```
utf8_strings = Iconv.iconv('utf-8', 'iso8859-1', *latin1_strings)
```

With newer Rubies, you can do things like this:

```
utf8_string = latin1_string.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

where `latin1_string` thinks it is in ASCII-8BIT but is really in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Note that Ruby now wants you to use `String#encode` rather than using `iconv`.

Comment: @duma: better now? I left the old Iconv stuff and added a short note about using `force_encoding` and `encode` instead of Iconv.

Comment: `CSV.foreach` worked for me, but I had to use `encoding: "iso-8859-1"` instead of `encoding: "ISO8859-1"`

Answer (score 36):

With ruby >= 1.9 you can use

```
file_contents = CSV.read("csvfile.csv", col_sep: "$", encoding: "ISO8859-1:utf-8")
```

The `ISO8859-1:utf-8` is meaning: The csv-file is ISO8859-1 - encoded, but convert the content to utf-8

If you prefer a more verbose code, you can use:

```
file_contents = CSV.read("csvfile.csv", col_sep: "$", 
    external_encoding: "ISO8859-1", 
    internal_encoding: "utf-8"
  )
```

Comment: This is awesome. Before, I had to put in a `bom` for this utf-16 csv: ```CSV.read('nom_nom_nom.csv', { :headers => true, :col_sep => "\t", :encoding => 'bom|utf-16le'})```, otherwise it would throw errors. 
Now it is:
```CSV.read('nom_nom_nom.csv', { :headers => true, :col_sep => "\t",
                   external_encoding: 'utf-16',
                   internal_encoding: "utf-8"})
```.

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with this issue for a while and not any of the other solutions worked for me.

The thing that made the trick was to store the conflictive *string* in a *binary* File, then read the File normally and using this *string* to feed the CSV module:

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new("conflictive_string")
tempfile.binmode
tempfile.write(conflictive_string)
tempfile.close
cleaned_string = File.read(tempfile.path)
File.delete(tempfile.path)
csv = CSV.new(cleaned_string)
```