# Ruby 1.9 encoding with Excel CSVs

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-1.9

I have some a Ruby script that reads in some CSV files, processes them, and writes out a (new) set of CSV files. I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and the new standard 'csv' gem (that used to be FasterCSV). The source CSV files contain non-ascii characters (é etc) but they are coming out of Excel so the encoding is not properly notated. Specifically, when I load the file into ruby I get this:

```
require 'csv'
t = CSV.table('file.csv',:converters=>nil)
t.to_s.encoding
# encoding is ASCII-8BIT
```

Even though the actual string is UTF-8. My issue is that I can't seem to get this string, which is marked as being ASCII to actually convert to UTF-8. When I try this:

```
require 'csv'
t = CSV.table('file.csv',:converters=>nil)
f = File.new('output.csv','w:utf-8')
f.write(t.to_s.force_encoding('utf-8'))
f.close
```

The output file is still listed as being encoded in ASCII. What do I need to do to get the output file to be encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: Please look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047944/ruby-read-csv-file-as-utf-8-and-or-convert-ascii-8bit-encoding-to-utf-8
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you've used Mac Excel to output the files they'll actually be MacRoman encoding, the code below may not be the best way to do it but it works

```
rows = []
CSV.foreach("../yourfile.csv", col_sep: ",", encoding: "MacRoman") do |row|
  rows << row.map! {|v| v.encode("UTF-8") unless v == nil } 
end
```

then you can convert to CSV::Table or whatever