# Read a csv file containing special characters(different spoken language)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, opencsv

I'm writing a csv file in Hindi(language), when I parse it I get different results.

For example, I make below csv file.

```
1234444070;आज आप कैसे हैं???
```

When I read the same file using `open(csv_aws_url).read`. I get:

```
"1234444070;\xE0\xA4\x86\xE0\xA4\x9C \xE0\xA4\x86\xE0\xA4\xAA \xE0\xA4\x95\xE0\xA5\x88\xE0\xA4\xB8\xE0\xA5\x87 \xE0\xA4\xB9\xE0\xA5\x88\xE0\xA4\x82???\r\n"
```

Can this happen that I read the same contents while parsing?

Comment: Try putting `puts` before your `open`. It looks like you're just seeing the `String#inspect` output, which is just a different visual representation of the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open(csv_aws_url).read.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `open(csv_aws_url, encoding: "utf-8").read`

The file is most likely being saved with a different encoding.

[Ruby read CSV file as UTF-8 and/or convert ASCII-8Bit encoding to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047944/ruby-read-csv-file-as-utf-8-and-or-convert-ascii-8bit-encoding-to-utf-8) should be helpful.

Comment: `open(csv_aws_url).read.force_encoding('utf-8')` did the trick!

Comment: This did the trick for me, thank you.