# Compass-style (ruby) encoding error

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

I just updated Ruby and now I'm getting the following error when trying to start compass:

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError on line ["28"] of /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.3/lib/sass/tree/visitors/to_css.rb: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

What's the problem there? How can it be solved?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286117/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I could fix it adding

```
encoding = "utf-8"
```

to the "config.rb" file

Comment: there's more than "config.rb" file, kindly would tell which one? thank you

Comment: @Mahmoud Adding this to the top of the config.rb in the root of my Sass/Compass project worked for me

Comment: Followup: if you’re using Grunt, change the Compass task’s `outputStyle` to a different value (`compressed`|`expanded`), save, run, then change back ([Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788561/codekit-encodingcompatibilityerror-after-upgrading-to-mavericks))