# "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 in mini magic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

I am doing these in my model

```
def self.get_store_resize_image(filename, store_id)

    filename=filename.gsub(' ', '%20')

    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(filename) #getting error here
    image.resize "252x185"  ## The thumbnail size

    temp_file_name="#{Time.now.to_time.to_i}_#{store_id}"
    @store_image_path="#{Rails.root}/public/tmp/#{temp_file_name}.png"
    @store_image="/tmp/#{temp_file_name}.png"
    image.write(@store_image_path)
    return @store_image
end
```

how can I fix "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 error ?

Comment: for what do you need a replace `(' ', '%20')`?

Comment: it seems that `filename`  before the code contains non-convertable to unicode char

Comment: have you tried filename.strip! instead of gsub ???

Comment: There is no character encoded with 0xFF in ASCII; ASCII has only 128 characters.

Comment: I have done ('', '%20') for image white space in name

Comment: but getting these error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6916663/3194468

Comment: is any other way I am on ror 4

Comment: gem 'mini_magick', '3.5.0' added these to gem file on place of gem 'mini_magick' it fixed thanks

Comment: Perhaps use `wb` when open a file for writing, e.g. `File.open(filename, 'wb')` see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-new