# seeds.rb utf-8? And how to fill table without model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8

I've got some problems with my seeds.rb file in my ruby on rails application.

Wen I prefill the database with the seeds.rb file I got this error when I start my application:

```
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

But the seeds.rb file is utf8 ... When I preffil with phpmyadmin all works fine.

**UPDATE:**

I have figured out from where the error comes.

```
<th><%=t("xyz.next_Time_at")%></th>
    <td>
        <%=l @xyz.next_Time %>
    </td>
```

Here I collect a date from Database for example:

```
2015-03-27 14:27:30
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286117/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8)

Comment: I've also found this ... but thes article dosn't solve the problem