# Problems during executing rails application. Version Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, debian

I have some problems running my ruby on rails app properly.

My app normaly runs with ruby 1.9.3 but I got lots of problems with utf-8 and ascii, so I updated ruby to 2.0.0

But now when I run my app with

```
 rails s
```

The app starts with ruby 2.0.0 but I haven't the writing permitions which were needed so I got lots of access errors.

If i run

```
sudo rails s
```

The app starts with ruby 1.9.3 ....

What do I have to do that the app starts with 2.0.0 when i run

```
sudo rails s
```

Update:
Thats the reason, why I tried to update to 2.0.0

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT):
1:
2: <fieldset>
3:   <legend><%= t("course.choose_start_date_legend") %></legend>
4:   <%= form_tag do %>
5:   <%= calendar_date_select_tag "start_date", @start_date, :time => true %>
6:       <%=
7:           my_date = Time.now + 6.days
```

app/views/courses/create_course.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_courses_create_course_html_erb___1293065742140947829_41081100'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed RVM? Use this link https://rvm.io/rvm/install for your reference. Using RVM you can control the version used in the app.

Comment: Before running the app have you used any RVM. e.g `rvm use 1.9.3@rails4.0.0`

Comment: I found this link should be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286117/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing RVM as @Uday proposed. I usually create a `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` file in my main application folder. In `.ruby-version` you put in your ruby version (`2.0.0`) and in `.ruby-gemset` the name of the gemset you want to use.

Gemsets tells bundle where to install your gems and I use them to separate different gem versions from each other. So one gemset per application you develop. (There are probably many other ways to keep different gem versions on a system, but this is a method that I find best).

When you have installed RVM you can:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

If  it is not installed on your system, RVM will tell you what to do.

Comment: okay Now it runs with 2.0.0: `
[2015-04-02 13:22:59] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-04-02 13:22:59] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-02-25) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-04-02 13:22:59] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=25021 port=3000`

But I have the same Problem with utf-8 like in 1.9.3 ... i've added the error above in question

Comment: It's not happy until now :( I have the same utf-8 error like bevor uprgading to 2.0.0, I've added the error in question

Comment: ;-) That is yet another problem. But just for the sake of testing: use `<form>...</form>` instead of  `<%= form_tag %>...<% end %>` to see what happens.

Comment: or use `utf8_enforcer_tag`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74337/discussion-between-thomas-and-felix).