# Why am I a getting ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT 
<td><%= simple_format(row.notes) %></td>
```

Here is my ERB file. The customer can type anything in the notes (ö, `, ", ', etc...)

If I delete this line `<td><%= simple_format(row.notes) %></td>`  then it says the incompatible error is the line above  `<td><%= row.notify_email %>`

If I then delete the `<td><%= row.notify_email %></td>` line it says the error is in the following lines (ending tr).

```
95:          
96:       </tr>
```

--

```
<% # encoding: utf-8 %>
<% content_for :head do -%>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
    });

    function editEvent(id){
      $('#eventDetailModal').modal('show');
      var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/ems/scheduled_call_details",
        type: "GET",
        data: {id : id},
        dataType: "json"
      });

      request.done(function(data) {
        $('#eventId').val(data._id);
        $('#pickup_address').val(data.pickup_address);
        $('#dropoff_address').val(data.dropoff_address);
        $('#phone').val(data.notify_phone);
        $('#email').val(data.notify_email);
        $('#notes').val(data.notes);
        $('#datepicker').val(data.edit_date);
        $('#send_hour').val(data.edit_hours);
        $('#send_minute').val(data.edit_minutes);
        $('input[name=ampm][value="' + data.edit_ampm + '"]').prop('checked', true);
        $('input[name=type][value="' + data.amb_type + '"]').prop('checked', true);
      });

      request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        alert("The request failed. Please close the dialog window and try again.")
      });
    }
  </script>
<% end -%>

<% if flash[:error] -%>
<div class="alert alert-error">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <strong>Edit Failed!</strong> <%= flash[:error] %>
</div>
<% end -%>
<% if flash[:notice] -%>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> <%= flash[:notice] %>
</div>
<% end -%>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>*</th>
      <th>Requester</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Pickup</th>
      <th>Dropoff</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% cur_month = nil %>
    <% @data.each do |row| %>
      <% if cur_month.nil? %>
      <% cur_month = row.send_time.strftime("%B") %>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center"><span class="lead"><strong><%= cur_month %></strong></span></td>
      </tr>
      <% elsif cur_month != row.send_time.strftime("%B") %>
      <% cur_month = row.send_time.strftime("%B") %>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center"><span class="lead"><strong><%= cur_month %></strong></span></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
      <% if row.send_time.utc < Time.now.utc -%>
      <tr style="background-color:#F5F5F5">
      <% elsif row.removed -%>
      <tr style="background-color:#EE8E8E">
      <% else -%>
      <tr>
      <% end -%>
        <td><%= link_to '<i class="icon-remove"></i>'.html_safe, url_for(:controller => "ems", :action => "delete_scheduled_call", :id =>  row.id.to_s), data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this scheduled call?"} %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:editEvent('<%= row.id.to_s %>')"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a></td>
        <td><%= User.find(row.user_id).email %></td>
        <td><a href="#" title="Send Alert: <%= format_date_calendar_time(row.warning_time, current_user) %>
Place Call: <%= format_date_calendar_time(row.actual_send_time, current_user) %>"><%= format_date_calendar_time(row.send_time, current_user) %></a></td>
        <td><%= row.pickup_address %></td>
        <td><%= row.dropoff_address %></td>
        <td><%= row.notify_phone %></td>
        <td><%= row.notify_email %></td>
        <td><%= simple_format(row.notes) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="eventDetailModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eventDetail" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Edit Event Details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_tag({:controller => :ems, :action => :edit_scheduled_call}, {:method => "post"}) do %>
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id="eventId">
      <label><strong>Pickup Address</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="pickup_address" id="pickup_address">

      <label><strong>Dropoff Address</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="dropoff_address" id="dropoff_address">

      <label><strong>Vehicle Type</strong></label>
      <% VehicleType.valid_types.each do |x| %>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="<%= x %>"><%= x %></br>
      <% end -%>

      <label><br/><strong>Phone</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">

      <label><strong>Email</strong></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

      <label><strong>Notes</strong></label>
      <textarea rows="3" name="notes" id="notes"></textarea>

      <label class="control-label" for="send_date"><strong>Date</strong></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="send_date" id="datepicker">
      </div>
      <label class="control-label" for="send_time"><strong>Time</strong></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="send_hour" class="input-mini" id="send_hour">
          <option value="01">01</option>
          <option value="02">02</option>
          <option value="03">03</option>
          <option value="04">04</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="06">06</option>
          <option value="07">07</option>
          <option value="08">08</option>
          <option value="09">09</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
        </select>:<select name="send_minute" class="input-mini" id="send_minute">
          <option value="00">00</option>
          <option value="05">05</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="15">15</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="25">25</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="35">35</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="45">45</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="55">55</option>
        </select> <input type="radio" name="ampm" value="AM" checked="checked">AM <input type="radio" name="ampm" value="PM">PM
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have all this already (see below) and the file is created 18 months ago in Sublime and has remained unchanged. Everything was working fine for 18 months. A customer typed something into the notes page and then this error happened. The DB is encrypted so I cannot see who typed what and what was typed.

Make sure config.encoding = "utf-8" is in the application.rb file.
Make sure you are using the 'mysql2' gem.
Put # encoding: utf-8 at the top of file containing UTF-8 characters.
Above the ::Application.initialize! line in the environment.rb file, add following two lines:

Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286117/incompatible-character-encodings-ascii-8bit-and-utf-8)

Comment: What versions of ruby and rails are you using?

Comment: No. Not duplicate. This page has remained unchanged for 18 months. A customer typed something into the NOTES field that screwed things up. The DB is encrypted so I cannot see which customer typed what. UPDATED

Comment: Using Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3... I am pretty sure it was an emoji . I have no idea how 1.9 deals with emojis (I believe, it does not.) Any reason to stay on ancient unsupported software?

Comment: We have a system that just prints money. We do not ever want to change it. We are not sure what will break if we do change it. The money is not good enough to make the changes or upgrades. What needs upgraded in your opinion?

Comment: @jdog, if the problem were with the NOTES field, removing `<td><%= simple_format(row.notes) %></td>` would do it, but you said that didn't work

Comment: You should check your template for invalids characters like BOM, you might be using a non-utf8 editor

Comment: I am using Sublime text 2

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/581553/sublime-text-2-encoding-utf-8